# passing variable from $(document).ready(function(){} to $(window).load(function() {}

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just imagine if I managed to create `percent_pass` at `document.ready`, how can I pass that var to `window.load`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    var question_count = $('.question-body').length;
    var question_percent = (1 / question_count) * 100;
    var color_percent = (300 / question_count);
    var percent_pass = 0;

    $('.answers input').click(function() {
      if ($(this).data('clicked') == false) {
        $(this).data('clicked', true);

        var old_height = $('.percent-solve').css('height');
        var new_height = parseInt(old_height) + color_percent;
        percent_pass += question_percent;

        if (percent_pass > 100) {
          percent_pass = 100;
        }
        $(".percentshow").html("%" + percent_pass);
        $('.count').text(percent_pass);
        $('.percent-solve').css('height', new_height + 'px');
        $('.count').each(function() {
          $(this).prop('Counter', percent_pass - question_percent).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
          }, {
            duration: 500,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function(now) {
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
          });
        });
        if (Math.ceil(percent_pass) == 100) {
          $('.end-test').css('color', '#ff9803');
        }
      }

      var q_count = $(this).parents('.question-body').attr("id");
      q_count = parseInt(q_count) + 1;
      $('.question-body').removeClass('open-question');
      $.scrollTo($('#' + q_count), 500, {
        onAfter: function() {
          $('#' + q_count).addClass('open-question');
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

$(window).load(function() {
  doughnutWidget.options = {
    container: $('#container'),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    class: 'myClass',
    cutout: 50
  };

  doughnutWidget.render(data());

  setInterval(init, 2000);
});

function init() {
  doughnutWidget.render(data());
}

function data() {
  var data = {
    pending: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#57B4F2',
    },
    delivered: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#6DED5C'
    },
    delayed: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#E63329',
    }
  };

  return data;
}
```

Comment: let me explain more :

Comment: "here is my nightmare" - yes `jQuery(function(){ jQuery(function(){` looks like nightmare

Comment: oops was typo , 2 jQuery(function() !!  i cant handle one god help with nested :D

Comment: it's corrected now .

Comment: anyway, jQuery function at that place is useless.

Comment: the document.ready works fine and change result on my html , it's just refuse to pass variable to another jquery ( window.load ) ...

Comment: For the 5th time... Because you define these vars inside document.ready - and that is the place where they are accessible from... Define them before, globally! - i'll update my answer with your "updated" code.
I'll probably leave this one to someone with more patience... (Because i am losing my nerves here)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139369/discussion-between-gadfly-and-adam-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT:

I have checked your website... Your problem is completely irrelevant to the variable scope... You are executing a script for a container element, that is non-existant in your HTML DOM, therefore the script fails.

---

Just use globalscope vars - 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

```js
//GlobalScope vars
var doughnutWidget = {/*Dummy js object, since i don't know douhnutWidget lib*/
    options: "",
    render: function() {
      return null;
    }
  },
  percent_pass;
//GlobalScope vars

$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(function() {

    percent_pass = 0;

  });
});

$(window).load(function() {
  doughnutWidget.options = {
    container: $('#container'),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    class: 'myClass',
    cutout: 50
  };

  doughnutWidget.render(data());

  setInterval(init, 2000);
  console.log("see? no errors, fnc data() returns"+data()+" (that should be correct)");
});

function init() {
  doughnutWidget.render(data());
}

function data() {

  var data = {
    pending: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#57B4F2',

    },
    delivered: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#6DED5C'
    },
    delayed: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#E63329',
    }
  };

  return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Your updated code

```js
var question_count,question_percent,color_percent,percent_pass;//THESE ARE NOW GLOBAL VARS!

var doughnutWidget={options:"",render:function(){}};//again, dummy object just to prevent console errors
$(document).ready(function() {
  question_count = $('.question-body').length;
  question_percent = (1 / question_count) * 100;
  color_percent = (300 / question_count);
  percent_pass = 0;
  $('.answers input').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('clicked') == false) {
      $(this).data('clicked', true);
      var old_height = $('.percent-solve').css('height');
      var new_height = parseInt(old_height) + color_percent;
      percent_pass += question_percent;

      if (percent_pass > 100) {
        percent_pass = 100;
      }
      $(".percentshow").html("%" + percent_pass);
      $('.count').text(percent_pass);
      $('.percent-solve').css('height', new_height + 'px');
      $('.count').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', percent_pass - question_percent).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
          duration: 500,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
        });
      });
      if (Math.ceil(percent_pass) == 100) {
        $('.end-test').css('color', '#ff9803');
      }

    }

    var q_count = $(this).parents('.question-body').attr("id");
    q_count = parseInt(q_count) + 1;
    $('.question-body').removeClass('open-question');
    $.scrollTo($('#' + q_count), 500, {
      onAfter: function() {
        $('#' + q_count).addClass('open-question');
      }
    });
  });
});

$(window).load(function() {
  doughnutWidget.options = {
    container: $('#container'),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    class: 'myClass',
    cutout: 50
  };

  doughnutWidget.render(data());

  setInterval(init, 2000);
});

function init() {
  doughnutWidget.render(data());
}

function data() {

  var data = {
    pending: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#57B4F2',

    },
    delivered: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#6DED5C'
    },
    delayed: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#E63329',
    }
  };

  return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi mate , would you please check my update again . it might help to find a solution ..

Comment: There are already 2 valid answers and yet it looks like you either don't understand what we are saying, or you are ignoring it... You define local variables inside functions. These local vars are only accessible inside that function and other nested functions. These variables cannot be taken "level higher"... You have to define these variables on top level - GLOBAL Scope - as i have posted w3schools link - read that and you will understand. Global vars should be accessible anywhere in your code.

Comment: thank you so much Adam k . i post some other question in chat , i appreciate your help . take care

Answer (score 0):

Update the percentage to a  and read it at window.load

Answer (score 0):

Try to place `var percent_pass = 0;` outside of your `$(document).ready()` function.
Your issue is with the scope of your variable.
Since it is defined in the callback function of ready() it is only available in its corresponding scope.

By placing `var percent_pass = 0;` outside of the callback function you change its scope to global. Try the following snippet

```js
var percent_pass; // declaration of the variable placed outside of any function => global variable

$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(function(){
      
        percent_pass = 0; // just assign a value.
       
        });
   });

$(window).load(function() {
  doughnutWidget.options = {
    container: $('#container'),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    class: 'myClass',
    cutout: 50
  };

  doughnutWidget.render(data());

  setInterval(init, 2000);
});

function init() {
  doughnutWidget.render(data());
}

function data() {
 
 var data = {
    pending: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#57B4F2',
    
    },
    delivered: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#6DED5C'
    },
    delayed: {
      val: Math.round(percent_pass),
      color: '#E63329',
    }
  };

  return data;
}
```

Comment: i try this before , sadly change in percent_pass dose not pass to math.round(percent_pass).